# Why this program repeats answers according to how many digits user inputs?

Tags: java, exception, binary, decimal, extend

The output is supposed to be the conversion of binary to decimal. When I run this program and input (for example) 101, it will print the answers 3 times because 101 is 3 digits. How do I fix this? I only need one answer. please help

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Bin2Dec {

public static void main (String[] args){
//Convert the input string to their decimal equivalent.
    //Open scanner for input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare variable s.
        String s;

        //Prompt user to enter binary string of 0s and 1s.
        System.out.print("Enter a binary string of 0's and 1's: ");
        //Save input to s variable.
        s = input.nextLine();

        //Create a loop using the length of user input as the maximum number.
        for (int i=0;i< s.length();i++){
            try {
             System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number "+ s +" is "+error(s));
              } catch (BinaryFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("There is an error in the entered binary string:"+e.getMessage());
              }
            }
          }

          public static int error(String parameter) throws BinaryFormatException {
            int tot = 0;
            for (int i = parameter.length(); i > 0; i--) {
              char c = parameter.charAt(i - 1);
              if (c == '1') tot += Math.pow(2, parameter.length() - i);
              else if (c != '0') throw new BinaryFormatException("'"+c+"' is not a binary digit");
            }
            return tot;
          } 
        }
```

Comment: Get rid of the `for (int i=0;i< s.length();i++){`

Comment: When things are happening more than once, there must be something looping somewhere

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you sir are awesome. I didn't realize I didn't need that. Thank you!! can i buy you dinner?

Comment: @agentmg123 Thanks for the offer, but just make sure, when you have the opportunity, to help other developers who might be struggling ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are invoking the method in a for loop:

```
for (int i=0;i< s.length();i++){
  try {
    System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number "+ s +" is "+error(s));
  } catch (BinaryFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("There is an error in the entered binary string:"+e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

so of course it will execute as many times as the number of characters in the input. Move the call to `error(s)` out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try and reinvent something that has already been done. Simply using [Integer#parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) should be enough:

```
public class Bin2Dec {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.print("Enter a binary string of 0's and 1's: ");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        int decoded = Integer.parseInt(input, 2);
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: @YassinHH, probably, yes. But even then he should have a look at the posted implentation for a reference of an example implementation

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the 'for' loop as shown:

```
//Create a loop using the length of user input as the maximum number.   
//for (int i=0;i< s.length();i++){
        try {
            System.out.println("The decimal value of the binary number "+ s +" is "+error(s));
             } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There is an error in the entered binary      
          string:"+e.getMessage());
          }
        }
      //}
```